# Rails tutorial - CSS and Image not being included

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am new to Ruby on Rails and am following the Rails Tutorials by Michael Hartl.

According to the book, I had downloaded a set of CSS and placed it in /public/stylesheets/ folder. Also, I had placed a logo.png file in public/images folder. When I request a page from the browser, the logo is not displayed and instead, the Alt text is displayed. Also, I think the CSS is not linked too.

I seemed to have done exactly what the book said. Not sure what the problem is.

Rails 3.2.8, ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

Here is the layout application.html.erb page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><%= title %></title>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print', :media => 'print' %>

<!--[if lt IE 8]><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/ie' %><![endif]-->

<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom', :media => 'screen' %>

</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
    <header>
        <%= image_tag("logo.png", :alt=>"Sample App", :class => "round") %>
        <nav class="round">
            <ul>
                <li><%= link_to "Home", '#' %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Help", '#' %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
    </header>

    <section class="round">
        <%= yield %>
    </section>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, i'm working my way through the tutorial too ... but you're working with the most recent version of rails, yet your code didn't sound familiar with me. So, I looked at Hartl's tutorial again ... your code comes from rails 3.0, yet you're using 3.2 version. Maybe that's what's causing the problem? Hartl did say that when following his tutorial to make sure that specs match what he's teaching in the tutorial. Not sure if this helps or not.

Comment: if you want to play around with different versions of rails, use a rvm. Here's a link for it: https://rvm.io/rvm/basics/. It allows you to use different version of rails, ruby, etc for different projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3.X has stylesheets in `app/assets/stylesheets`, and images in `app/assets/images`.

The other advice is good too... use the latest version of the tutorial and check out rvm.

Comment: Thanks!  Was so glad to find this old thread with this answer

Answer (score 1):

Why are you following older edition of the tutorial? There is slightly newer version on his site. You should definitely check it out.

Are you using Rails 3? If you are, the proper place to put your stylesheets is now in assets. You can find them in app/assets/ stylesheets.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know of the updated version on the site, I will use that now instead of the book.